# Can NSLog() format more than eight doubles in Swift?

Tags: swift, number-formatting, nslog

When I try to format more than eight doubles in NSLog() in Swift, the first eight are fine.  The remaining doubles often incorrectly come out as 0.0.  Occasionally, instead of 0.0, I get a really long number like

```
1143028425600163529287784455055173199670798747070639575063120152283070194166043387484791550160425300628149851402570478008077137648389330869144763352222012984900499165551916115751227038304582371235517382094416130757884235441564878725430349135872.000000
```

I see this for ios and os x.

Here's my main.swift running from Xcode:

```
import Foundation

let a : [Double] = (1...10).map({ 0.5 + Double($0) })
let b : [Int] = (1...10).map({ $0 })
NSLog("Ten doubles \(a)")
NSLog("Ten integers \(b)")
NSLog("Ten doubles again %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9])
NSLog("Ten integers again %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8], b[9])
```

Here's the output:

```
2016-03-27 21:52:47.676 testStuff[25971:6046917] Ten doubles [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5]
2016-03-27 21:52:47.677 testStuff[25971:6046917] Ten integers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2016-03-27 21:52:47.677 testStuff[25971:6046917] Ten doubles again 1.500000 2.500000 3.500000 4.500000 5.500000 6.500000 7.500000 8.500000 0.000000 0.000000
2016-03-27 21:52:47.677 testStuff[25971:6046917] Ten integers again 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The weirdness is the third line of output above ending in "0.000000 0.000000."  That should be "9.500000 10.500000."  Using %f or %.2lf instead of %lf doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is this a bug?

I don't need a workaround.  I just want to know if I'm missing something.

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug to me. The same happens with `let s1 = String(format: "%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9]) ; print(s1)`.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR.  Good to know it's a more general problem with the string formatter.